# How to iterate through a table and perform query for each row in the table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have

```
User table[user_id]
Disperse Table [order_id, disperse_amount]
Pool Table [user_id, order_id]
```

For each *order_id* in Disperse, I want to insert **x** random rows of [user.user_id, disperse.order_id] into pool table. (**x** is the current row's disperse_amount)

Might be more understandable with the query I have so far:

```
WITH p as (
    SELECT *
    FROM pool p
    WHERE p.order_id= **disperse.order_id** (from current disperse row)
)
INSERT INTO pool (order_id, user_id)
SELECT **disperse.order_id**, user_id
FROM users
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
    SELECT 1 
    FROM p 
    WHERE user_id = users.user_id
    )
ORDER BY random()
LIMIT **disperse.disperse_amount** (from the current disperse row)
```

This could work for ONE row in the distributer table.

I just need to iterate through all rows of distributer table [order_id, disperse_amount], and for each row, perform this query.

There may be a much more efficient way to do this, but I wouldn't know as I'm a novice to postgres and webdev in general.

Comment: Provide some sample data for people to work with. Also, the rows you insert into Pool comes from the table Users with no condition on Order_id; i.e. it will mix-up all users with all orders; is this intended?

Comment: Could an order already have entries in the pool table? For example, what if an order had a disperse_amount of 5 but already had 3 entries in the pool? Do we add 2? Do we add 5 more? And, presumably, a user can only be assigned once to an order? That is [user_id, order_id] is unique? Real table definitions, sample data, and your desired results would help clarify.

Comment: At this point, yes it is intended to have all orders and user IDs in the same table. Because when the user connects to the database it will query the pool table for all Rows matching their user ID.

Comment: Yes [user id, order ID] is unique in pool. That is why I added the WHERE NOT EXISTS.

Comment: Also let's say that the disbursement was 5, there are 10 users in the user table and 6 of them have already been put into the pool table with that order ID. That means that only the remaining 4 users can be put into the order pool. I have not figured what to do at that point. Right now I'm trying to figure out how to iterate over it every order that needs to be dispersed

Comment: Please edit your question with the additional details. And again, real table definitions with sample data and expected results will help us understand. Here's another question: what happens if disperse_amount is greater than the number of users?

Comment: If the disperse amount is greater than users (or users that have not already been added to the pool) I'd just insert maximum available users, haven't figured out what to do after that

Answer (score 0):

Any time you want to iterate in SQL, there's a better way.

Here we can use a `cross join lateral` to match up each entry in disbursements with the appropriate random picks from users. A [cross join](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-cross-join/) matches every row in a one table with every row in another table. [`lateral`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) evaluates the subquery for each row; this allows us to use `limit d.disburse_amount`.

```
select
  u.id as user_id,
  d.order_id as order_id
from disbursements d
cross join lateral (
  select id
  from users
  order by random()
  limit d.disburse_amount
) u
```

---

What if there are already entries in order_pool? Let's assume we don't want to go over the disburse_amount *and* we don't want to repeat any user_ids for the same order.

First, we need to know how many disbursements remain for each order.

```
select
  d.order_id,
  d.disburse_amount - count(op.user_id) as remaining_disbursements
from disbursements d
left join order_pool op on op.order_id = d.order_id

-- For this group by to work, order_id must be the primary key
-- of disbursements. Then PostgreSQL knows each order_id can have
-- only one disburse_amount; disburse_amount is 
-- "functionally dependent" on order_id.
-- If not, `sum(d.disburse_amount)`.
group by d.order_id
```

Then we select from the query above instead of disbursements, and cross join lateral as before with the extra clause to exclude users who are already in the pool. Cross join lateral, as before, lets us do this for each order.

```
with order_disbursements_remaining as (
  select
    d.order_id,
    d.disburse_amount - count(op.user_id) as remaining_disbursements
  from disbursements d
  left join order_pool op on op.order_id = d.order_id
  group by d.order_id
)
select u.id, odr.order_id
from order_disbursements_remaining odr
cross join lateral (
  select id
  from users
  where id not in (
    select user_id
    from order_pool
    where order_id = odr.order_id
  )
  order by random()
  limit odr.remaining_disbursements
) u
```

This can safely be run as an insert trigger on the disbursements table to keep the order pool up to date on new disbursements. Deletes and updates must be handled separately.

Comment: I vote for a randomised `tablesample` clause: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/IF2NTS8b). Otherwise you are re-scanning the whole table for each row, to call random() for each row of that, then sort that each time, then discard via `limit`.

Comment: @Schwern
I do appreciate you helping with that, I hope to use the cross join lateral, but not sure if it will work with the next part I want to do.

Is there a way when doing the cross join lateral, that for all rows that had   less rows than the LIMIT amount, add that row order_id and the difference to a temp table? 

(for example if one of the rows in dispersal only output 2 rows, but the LIMIT was 3, the difference is 1, so it would be saved to a temp_table with columns order_id and left_over

Comment: Then for each of the rows in temp_table, back in order_pool table I would get the rows with those order_ids and with a status of -1(expired). with that result, ORDER by [expired_at] time , LIMIT it to temp_table.left_over, and UPDATE those rows status to 0 (active). This may have to be iterated over instead of cross join lateral.

What I'm trying to do, is after I have attempted to give an order to all users, instead loop through previously asked users that let the orders expire, and re-activate them so they have a second chance to complete the order.

Comment: btw A secondary cron job has been checking the order_pool for expired orders [if current_time> column expired_time) and setting them to -1(expired). When this happens it would adds 1 extra disperse_amount to it's related order_id in the dispersal table, so the next time the dispersal function runs, it will try to insert/update that many more orders.

I know it may be hard to understand what I'm explaining, as I am struggling understanding it myself. If you're willing, I could give more info on the tables to show what is going on.

Comment: @Schwern Sure, I am definitely interested in your contact info! I am at the point where I almost have my task dispersal system working, but I am sure it's not production ready.  It either needs major optimizing, or rebuilding from ground up.